# How to find specific supported versions of plugins to Jenkins 2.289.3

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins

I have installed Jenkins version of 2.289.3 and many plugins are not supporting and required latest version of Jenkins. I can't update the Jenkins to latest

I tried to download the specific plugins from plugins.jenkins.io but can't predict which version of plugin will work and need to download the multiple lower versions of plugins try to upload it in the jenkins

Is there any way to find exact versions of plugins that I can directly install on Jenkins or download

Comment: Just goto https://your-jenkins-url/pluginManager/available and you'll get the list of compatible plugins there. If you want a specific plugin, search for the plugin in https://plugins.jenkins.io/ site and look at the required jenkins version there. or you can goto the plugin's source in github and check for releases or tags for the supported jenkins version and then manually upload the hpi file?

Comment: In the jenkins plugin manager getting the compatible plugins but are available for newer versions of jenkins